# Class 'RainLab\Blog\Classes\TagProcessor' not found

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I'm working with octobercms, when I run `php artisan` command on working directory. I'm getting the following error

[image]

Please anyone tell me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: did you run `composer install`?

Comment: yes, Its working. Previously the artisan command worked well. I encountered this issue after pulling the code from Github

Comment: are you using octobercms?

Answer (score 0):

Just update the RainLab.Blog plugin in your project. If not will not work then delete directory this plugin from your project and install again this plugin.

Answer (score -1):

> run following commands this will solve your problem.

1. `php artisan dump-autoload`
2. `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: composer........